# Kits19 challenge

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm trying to run kits19 challenge's repo in Windows 10 but facing a lot of errors related to directory, path. While trying to train RESUNET, I'm getting this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_res_unet.py", line 262, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\CS\Anaconda\envs\goru\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\CS\Anaconda\envs\goru\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\CS\Anaconda\envs\goru\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "D:\CS\Anaconda\envs\goru\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train_res_unet.py", line 63, in main
    use_roi=False, train_transform=transform, valid_transform=transform)
  File "F:\Uni\203\cse465\kits19-challenge\dataset\kits19.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._get_data(train_case_ids_file, valid_case_ids_file, test_case_ids_file)
  File "F:\Uni\203\cse465\kits19-challenge\dataset\kits19.py", line 67, in _get_data
    train_imgs, train_labels, train_case_slice_num = self._read_npy(self._root, self._train_case, is_test=False)
  File "F:\Uni\203\cse465\kits19-challenge\dataset\kits19.py", line 106, in _read_npy
    case_root = root / data / f'case_{case:05d}'
  File "D:\CS\Anaconda\envs\goru\lib\site-packages\pathlib2\__init__.py", line 1102, in __truediv__
    return self._make_child((key,))
  File "D:\CS\Anaconda\envs\goru\lib\site-packages\pathlib2\__init__.py", line 878, in _make_child
    drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
  File "D:\CS\Anaconda\envs\goru\lib\site-packages\pathlib2\__init__.py", line 824, in _parse_args
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not module
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not module

simply means that whatever is being passed in `a = os.fspath(a)` is not of a `path-like` object, and it's of type `module`. A module in python is simply a file consisting of Python code.

I don't see how the error can be mapped to a file but I would suggest you upgrade your `Python` version and make sure you are meeting all the pre-requisites of the repo you are trying to run. It could also be that this was not made to run on `Windows`.